# Excluding files on GitHub pull

Tags: github

I know how to ignore files on pushing to GitHub, but how can I ignore all .php files on pulling? Our GitHub is pulled to several locations, but at one of the locations we can't allow any php files (for security measures).

I've read alot, but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make a selective pull using Git. The easyest way to achieve this is using branchs.

- Branch1: This branch will contain all files that are not php files
- Branch2: This branch will contain only php files

Then, on the location that can't allow php files, make the pull only from Branch1. On the other locations, make the pull from Branch1 and Branch2 and it will merge automatically.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hmm. So how do I split the original files into two branches?

Comment: You can do that in many ways, but I think that the easiest way is creating the branch2 from the HEAD of your branch with all your files (lets suppose that is master). Then if you delete all your .php files on master, master will be the branch without the PHP files. Then go to branch2 and delete all the files that are not .php